# How to reduce space between unordered list and its previous element(center)?

Tags: html, css, list

Consider the header in the following image:

[image]

I am using the following HTML and CSS code for the header.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <center><h1>Knowledge Explorer</h1></center>
    <ul id="customlist">
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Compare</a></li>            
        <li><a href="#">Connect</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #header {
        background-color:#787878;
        color:white;
        padding:0.2px;
    }
    #customlist li{
        display: inline;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding-right:20px;
    }
```

I want to reduce space between "Knowledge Explorer" and list elements. Is it possible to do that ? I also want to change the color of list elements. I didn't find a way to do these. Can someone explain how to do these ?

Thank you.

Comment: `#header h1 { margin: 0; } #customlist li{ color: #ffffff; }` should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `<h1>` and `<ul>` elements have default margin on the bottom and top, respectively. Adjust or remove them and your gap is gone:

```
h1{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#customlist{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6p5o279x/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the default margins on the `<h1>` & `<ul>` tags.

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color:#787878;
    color:white;
    padding:0.2px;
}

#header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#customlist {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#customlist li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```